# How can i use the same design with different data different pages in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component called home pages where navbar i using i like use this same navber with my another component called shop.js with different data

This is the home component

```
const Home = () => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Header/>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

This is the header component

```
const Header = () => {
    return (
        <header>
            <TopModal/>
            <Navbar/>
            <HeroSlider/>
        </header>
    );
};
```

This is the Shop.js components

```
export default function Shop() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {/*this component coming from home component*/}
            <Header/>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

I want to change the navbar value in shop.js?

Comment: Please share your `Navbar` component code too.

Answer (score 0):

**make a separate component of the navbar** and add the navbar component in the **app.js file** which will add the navbar to all files or add the navbar component to other component files in which you want the navbar  and **use props** to change the button or data of the navbar

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `children` property of the `Header` component to pass your own components:

```js
const Header = ({children}) => {
    let navbar = Navbar
    if (children.length) {
       navbar = children[0]
    }
    return (
        <header>
            <TopModal/>
            {navbar}
            <HeroSlider/>
        </header>
    );
};
```

Your Home component will be the same, while your Shop instead:

```js
export default function Shop() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Header>
                <ShopNavbar/>
            </Header>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```